# Line graph in R, groups of three lines and group background

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I would like to create the following graph in R:

[image]

but improving the following:

- Groups of three lines with the same color
- Common fill background for each group, similar to a confidence interval, with a mean, upper, and lower boundaries.

How can this be done in R?

Thank you!

PS: if you think that another kind of graph is more suitable to visualize this data, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest to take some ggplot tutorials. Maybe the cookbook is also a good place to start http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/

Comment: If you do want to specifically inquire about the above graph, [I would also suggest you read how to produce a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You may modify your question so that there is enough information for the community to help you.  The general graph you describe is certainly possible with R and `ggplot2`; however, we would need to see some representative data (share via `dput(your.data)` if at all possible), and your knowledge so far.  If you're totally stuck, give it a go and share with us where you are.  We are glad to help!

Comment: Are you still interested in solving this problem? Let me know if it was so.

Comment: @MarekFiołka Yes, I am still interested in a solution to this problem, much appreciated.

Comment: I would be grateful for sharing with me the data you want to visualize this way. Can you do this?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show me your details. So I had to generate them myself. I hope that's what you meant.

```
library(tidyverse)

df = tribble(
~line,  ~amin,  ~a, ~amax,  ~bmin,      ~b,   ~bmax,
 "L1",  0.2,     4.5,     7.0,  990.0,   825.0,   750.0,
 "L2",  8.0,    17.5,    27.0,  800.0,   375.0,   -50.0,
 "L3",  29.0,   43.0,    46.0,  150.0,  -450.0,  -500.0,
 "L4",  44.0,   49.0,    56.0,    0.0,  -150.0,  -400.0,
 "L5",  62.0,   66.0,    88.0, -300.0,  -300.0, -1200.0)

  
df = df %>% 
  mutate(
    line = line  %>% as.factor(),
    x = list(c(50,  150))) %>% 
  unnest(x) %>% 
  mutate(
    y = a*x + b,
    ymin = amin*x + bmin,
    ymax = amax*x + bmax
  )

df %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x, y,  color = line,   fill = line)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), alpha = .4)+
  geom_line(size=2)
```

[image]